# subversion UUID mismatch

Tags: linux, svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [recreating svn repository](https://serverfault.com/questions/55511/recreating-svn-repository)

I am using subversion under /var/svn path in my server..

I have two folder

- lumin
- html5

Two groups are using these two repositories

My issue is first repo "lumin" is working fine. The second repository "html5" was unable to commit the end. The problem returns with:

> "svn: Repository UUID 'dfaaf395-1305-4651-99ff-278f51fa8ecf' doesn't
>   match expected UUID '0e2ea83a-f59e-4c48-9f8c-2ab2ea8ccea0'

How to create a svn UUID in the subversion..
I am using the html5 repository from /var/svn/html5

Storing the users password from /etc/group2

Can any one help me out how to create uuid with correct syntax. I'm new to this type of environment issues..

Regards
Karthick

Answer (score -1):

You can change the uuid in the [repo]/db/uuid file.  Try changing the contents of that file to the expected UUID.

Edit: Note that each working copy's UUID must match the repository it was checked out from.  In this case it sounds like the UUID was inadvertently changed so it would make sense to revert it in order to preserve the existing working copies.  If you have old working copies with the old UUID and new working copies with the new one then you'll have to choose the lesser of two evils.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a great idea. Subversion must store that UUID so that it can do certain checks, and forcefully changing it will bypass those checks and potentially cause corruption.

Comment: Alternatively you could re-checkout that working copy and it will have the 'new' UUID when you do so.  Somewhere along the way someone did a checkout with UUID1 and now it's UUID2.

Comment: FYI minus oners, this has been an svnadmin command since v1.5 so there is a time and a place for changing it: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.setuuid.html